# How to migrate from one Git repo to another Git repo?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I need to do a migration from one Git repo to another Git repo. The destination is not empty. Someone in the past already did this work apparently, but now all the branches are outdated.

This is the situation:

Source remote repository: `repo_source`

branches:

- branch_A
- branch_B
- branch_C
- branch_D

Destination remote repository: `repo_dest`
branches:

- branch_A
- branch_B

The idea is to have the missing branches (branch_C, branch_D) and the already existing branches (branch_A, branch_B) need to be updated with the new data.

As example here there are just 4 branches, but in realty is way more. So, is there a way (a script) for make this migration simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone repository repo_source using the git clone command.

```
git clone repo_source
```

Once done,

```
git remote add repo_dest repo_dest_url
git push --force --all repo_dest
```

This should replace all the destination branches too even if it exists.

Comment: I'd advise to first try without `--force` and if it works that's great, if it doesn't consider the problem before forcing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `repo_dest` repository as another remote and then pull and merge the changes locally and push them.

Try the below from your local working directory;

```
git remote add new_origin ORIGIN_URL           # add new remote
git pull new_origin branch_A                   # pull, merge branch_A and fix conflicts (if any)
git pull new_origin branch_B                   # pull, merge branch_B and fix conflicts (if any)
git push new_origin branch_A                   # push each branch to the new remote
git push new_origin branch_B
git push new_origin branch_C
git push new_origin branch_D
```

Comment: Yes, I was doing something like that, but I get the message
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'repo_dest'.
Everything up-to-date. And nothing really happens

It seems like it is ignoring --all param

Comment: then don't use `--all`. Push each branch separately.

Comment: another thing you can do. Checkout `master` to a new branch, delete local `master` branch, push all branches, restore master branch.